# How to bin Colour values (categorical- high cardinality) to primary colours?

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering, image-classification, python-3.x

I have a colour variable with values for different e-commerce products like - `olive, teal, blue, green etc.`

I want to bin these colours to the primary colour values.

eg -

```
olive ---> green
teal ----> blue
blue and green will remain the same.
```

I also have images available of these products, therefore, I am wondering if there is any solution using some clustering technique or using a pre-trained model for classification in some way.

Comment: You can calculate euclidian distance (three dimentions: red, green, blue) to prime colors. The closest color is your best match.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are small, finite number of color options, it would be straightforward to manually create a dictionary where the key is the primary color and values are a set of other color values.

In Python, it would be something like:

```py
colors = {"blue": {"blue", "teal"},
          "green": {"green", "olive"},
         }
```